# How to replace space with '+' symbol in a triangular array?

Tags: diagrams

How can I make number pattern like this

[image]

But, all spaces are replaced with plus signs ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: In the final row of your screenshot, should there be a space between `10` and `11`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's employ Ti*k*Z and some simple algorithms for such things.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5ex,y=5ex]
\def\maxnum{11} % Change the size here
\foreach \i in {1,...,\maxnum} {
    % Draw the numbers
    \pgfmathsetmacro\auxnum{\maxnum-\i+1}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\auxnum} 
        \node (\i-\j) at (\i,\j) {\i};
    % Draw the plus signs
    \ifnum\i=\maxnum\relax\else
        \pgfmathsetmacro\auxnum{\maxnum-\i}
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\auxnum} 
            \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(.5,0)}]\i-\j.base) {+};
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A little bonus:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5ex,y=5ex]
\def\maxnum{11}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\maxnum} {
    % Draw the numbers
    \pgfmathsetmacro\auxnum{\maxnum-\i+1}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\auxnum} 
        \node (\i-\j) at (\i,\j) {\i};
    % Draw the plus signs
    \ifnum\i=\maxnum\relax\else
        \pgfmathsetmacro\auxnum{\maxnum-\i}
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\auxnum} 
            \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(.5,0)}]\i-\j.base) {+};
    \fi
    % The rest :)
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sumoutput{int((\maxnum-\i+1)*(\maxnum-\i+2)/2)}
    \node (output-\i) at (\maxnum+1,\i) {\sumoutput};
    \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(-.5,0)}]output-\i.base) {=};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Not sure what do you really want to get by "to the right", but maybe this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5ex,y=5ex]
\def\maxnum{11}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\maxnum} {
    % numbers - simpler than the above code
    \foreach \j [count=\k] in {\i,...,1}
        \node (\i-\j) at (\i,\j) {\k};
    % plus signs - a bit simpler
    \ifnum\i=\maxnum\relax\else
        \foreach \j in {\i,...,1} 
            \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(.5,0)}]\i-\j.base) {+};
    \fi
    % I keep the "bonus" part - it needs no improvements
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sumoutput{int((\maxnum-\i+1)*(\maxnum-\i+2)/2)}
    \node (output-\i) at (\maxnum+1,\i) {\sumoutput};
    \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(-.5,0)}]output-\i.base) {=};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Comparison with other answers

Other answers are very good, but it seems that this answer is totally different from all other answers (which are somehow a little similar to each other). This is the pros and cons of this answer compared to the others. Read it to consider what to use.

#### Pros

The numbers and signs are aligned in a perfect square. So you can have something like this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5ex,y=5ex]
\def\maxnum{11} % Change the size here
\foreach \i in {1,...,\maxnum} {
    % numbers - simpler than the above code
    \foreach \j [count=\k] in {\i,...,1}
        \node[minimum size=.55cm] (\i-\j) at (\i,\j) {\k};
    % plus signs - a bit simpler
    \ifnum\i=\maxnum\relax\else
        \foreach \j in {\i,...,1} 
            \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(.5,0)}]\i-\j.base) {+};
    \fi
    % I keep the "bonus" part - it needs no improvements
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sumoutput{int((\maxnum-\i+1)*(\maxnum-\i+2)/2)}
    \node (output-\i) at (\maxnum+1,\i) {\sumoutput};
    \node[anchor=base] at ([shift={(-.5,0)}]output-\i.base) {=};
}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\path[fill=red!10,draw=red,thick] 
    ([shift={( .1,-.1)}]1-1.north west) -- 
    ([shift={( .1,-.1)}]11-11.north west) 
    arc (135:-45:{.55/sqrt(2)}) --
    ([shift={(-.1, .1)}]1-1.south east) 
    arc (315:135:{.55/sqrt(2)}); % Well, possibly this is not the best
                                 % way to draw this, but this is only
                                 % for illustration purpose.
\draw[red,thick,<-] 
    ($([shift={( .1,-.1)}]1-1.north west)!.45!([shift={( .1,-.1)}]11-11.north west)$)
    -- + (-2,1) node[pos=1.3] {Looks! All are number 1!};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In other answers, the numbers, say 1, are not perfectly aligned if `\maxnum` is greater than 9, so it is harder to draw such a path.

#### Cons

It is very clear: the spacing between the numbers and the plus signs are inconsistent. But when I follow this approach (insert the plus signs separately), I have to accept this kind of spacing.

Btw, the numbers after the equal signs are not right-aligned. This is fixable, but a fix will make the code much more complicated (if I want to automatically determine the width of the node of the "sum"). I don't think this is a major problem though.

Comment: What if you want to make it align to the right ? What is this TikZ thing ? (I'm a very-beginner)

Comment: Hello @LimoPanda, if you want to know what Ti*k*Z is good for, please have a look at p. 18 of [this manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzlings/tikzlings-doc.pdf). ;-)

Comment: @LimoPanda Sorry for the late reply. What do you want to align to the right?

Comment: @marmot I thought it should be pages 18 _and_ 11-12 of that manual

Comment: Can you generalize your solutions so that `11` (the number of rows of the triangular array) isn't hard-coded?

Comment: @Mico Sure. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 24):

Just for fun: without packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcounter{pfft}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{pft}{0}\loop%
\stepcounter{pft}%
\setcounter{pfft}{0}{\noindent$\loop%
\stepcounter{pfft}\number\value{pfft}%
\ifnum\number\value{pfft}<\number\value{pft}+\repeat$\par}%
\ifnum\number\value{pft}<11\repeat%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `pgffor`, which contains the `\foreach` command that is used in [JouleV's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489243/121799), and which is loaded by Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,11}%
{\noindent$\foreach \Y in {1,...,\X}%
{\ifnum\Y>1%
+%
\fi%
\Y
}$\par}
\end{document}
```

Since everyone has a bonus...

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcounter{pfft}
\newcounter{sum}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\setcounter{pft}{0}\loop%
\stepcounter{pft}%
\setcounter{pfft}{0}\setcounter{sum}{0}{\noindent$\loop%
\stepcounter{pfft}\number\value{pfft}\addtocounter{sum}{\value{pfft}}%
\ifnum\number\value{pfft}<\number\value{pft}+\repeat=\number\value{sum}%
\ifnum\value{sum}<10\relax\phantom{1}\fi$\par}%
\ifnum\number\value{pft}<11\repeat%
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also make this work with `align` by using a recursion (which I learned from David Carlisle in the chat, if I remember correctly, but my realization is much more elegant because instead of `zz`, which is deprecated, I use `pft` ;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{pft}
\newcounter{pfft}
\newcounter{sum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\Pft{\stepcounter{pft}\number\value{pft}\addtocounter{sum}{\number\value{pft}}\ifnum\number\value{pft}<\number\value{pfft}%
+\Pft\else%
&=\number\value{sum}\\
\fi}
\def\Pfft{\stepcounter{pfft}\setcounter{pft}{0}\setcounter{sum}{0}\Pft%
\ifnum\number\value{pft}<11\relax%
\Pfft%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{pfft}{0}
\begin{align*}
\Pfft
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The number of rows can be set as the argument of the LaTeX macro `\makearray`; this macro calls the Lua function `make_array`, which does most of the work.

[image]

To make the triangular array right-aligned instead of left-aligned, change `\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}` to `\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}`. If you wish to have a bit more space around the `+` symbols, change `tex.sprint ( "{+}" )` to `tex.sprint ( "+" )`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment

%% Lua-side code: Define the Lua function 'make_array'
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function make_array ( n )
  for i=1,n do
    for j=1,i do
      tex.sprint ( j )
      if j<i then 
        tex.sprint ( "{+}" )
      else
        tex.sprint ( "\\\\" )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: Define the macro '\makearray'
\newcommand\makearray[1]{%
    $\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    \directlua{make_array(#1)}
    \end{array}$
}

\begin{document}
\makearray{11}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a solution which typesets each row's sum along the right-hand edge of the (now rectangular) array. Compared with the solution shown above, it also allows for a bit more space around the `+` symbols. Observe the use of `\toprule` and `bottomrule`: These instruction are optional and may be left off.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}  % for '\luaexec' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\toprule' and '\bottomrule' macros

%% Lua-side code: Define the function 'make_array_with_rowsum'
\luaexec{%
```

```lua
function make_array_with_rowsum ( n )
  for i=1,n do
    for j=1,i do
      tex.sprint ( j )
      if j<i then 
        tex.sprint ( "+" )
      else
        tex.sprint ( "&{{}={}}&" .. i*(i+1)//2 .. "\\\\" )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
}

%% LaTeX-side code: Define the macro '\makearray'
\newcommand\makearray[1]{%
   \par\noindent
   \begingroup
   \centering
   \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
   $\begin{array}{lcr}
      \toprule
      \luadirect{make_array_with_rowsum(#1)}
      \bottomrule
   \end{array}$\par
   \endgroup}

\begin{document}
\makearray{16}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\noindent$1$
\multido{\iA=2+1}{10}{\\$%
  \multido{\iB=1+1}{\numexpr\iA-1}{\iB+}\iA$}

\bigskip\noindent$1=1$
\multido{\iA=2+1}{10}{\\$\xdef\Sum{0}%
    \multido{\iB=1+1}{\numexpr\iA-1}{%
        \iB+\xdef\Sum{\the\numexpr\Sum+\iB}}\iA=\the\numexpr\Sum+\iA$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The mandatory double `expl3` loop:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\triangletab}{sm}
 {% #1 = * for totals, #2 = end point
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{} c @{} r @{}}
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 } { \panda_row_total:n { ##1 } \\ }
    \end{tabular}
   }
   {
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 } { \panda_row:n { ##1 } \\ }
    \end{tabular}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \panda_row:n
 {
  $1 \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { #1 } { + ##1 }$
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \panda_row_total:n
 {
  \panda_row:n { #1 } & ${}={}$ & $\int_eval:n { (#1)*(#1+1)/2 }$
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\triangletab{1} \qquad \triangletab{3} \qquad \triangletab{11}
\]

\[
\triangletab*{1} \qquad \triangletab*{3} \qquad \triangletab*{11}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]